# Prove that the two powers are equal

Tags: number-theory, summation, exponentiation

> Prove that: $$\dfrac{1}{2^{180}a^{360}}\dfrac{(a^{720}-1)(a^2-1)}{a^{2}+1} = \dfrac{\left(1+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{180} - \left(1-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{180}}{\sqrt{3}}$$ where: $$a = \dfrac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

This seemed like a very challenging question but the fact that we have a telescoping binomial sum in the numerator of the LHS helps. I think if we can simplify the LHS sufficiently we might be able to prove it by just equating both sides of the equation.

Comment: Possible hint: $a = 2 \cos \frac \pi{12}$. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Observe that $a^2=2+\sqrt3$

$\implies1+\dfrac{\sqrt3}2=\dfrac{a^2}2$ 
and $1-\dfrac{\sqrt3}2=\dfrac1{2a^2}$

Use [Componendo and Dividendo](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/) to find $\dfrac{a^2-1}{a^2+1}=?$

Now

$$\dfrac{1}{2^{180}a^{360}}\dfrac{(a^{720}-1)(a^2-1)}{a^{2}+1}=\left[\left(\dfrac{a^2}2\right)^{180}-\left(\dfrac1{2a^2}\right)^{180}\right]\cdot\dfrac{a^2-1}{a^2+1}$$

Can you reach home from here?

Comment: How do I use this fact?

Comment: @user19405892, Updated

Comment: Can you explain the compenendo part?

Comment: @user19405892, $$\dfrac{1}{2^{180}a^{360}}(a^{720}-1)=\dfrac1{2^{180}}\left(a^{360}-\dfrac1{a^{360}}\right)=\dfrac1{2^{180}}\left((a^2)^{180}-\dfrac1{(a^2)^{180}}\right)$$

Comment: Impressive algebra!

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I am still wondering about how to find $\dfrac{a^2-1}{a^2+1}$.

Comment: @user19405892, See the link in the answer OR http://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Junior%20Secondary/Componendo%20et%20Dividendo.htm.  Otherwise, put the value of $a^2$ in $$\dfrac{a^2-1}{a^2+1}$$ straightaway

Comment: I don't get how it can be done using compenendo dividendo. Please show the steps.

Comment: @user19405892, $$\dfrac{a^2}1=\dfrac{2+\sqrt3}1$$  $$\iff\dfrac{a^2-1}{a^2+1}=\dfrac{2+\sqrt3-1}{2+\sqrt3+1}$$  $$=\dfrac{1+\sqrt3}{\sqrt3(\sqrt3+1)}=\dfrac1{\sqrt3}$$